# What is the theoretical charge radius of a proton?

Tags: protons

Today I read this [news article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/09/190905145426.htm) and this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle) that talk about the 'Proton radius puzzle', where discrepancies have been observed between values of the proton charge radius, when measured using different experimental techniques.

However, I was wondering, what is the theoretical charge radius of a proton (based on current theory)? Both the news article and Wikipedia page talk a lot about experimental measurements, but there is very little mention of theory. I am wondering how the best current theoretical prediction compares to the measurements.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00313 and references therein to other QCD lattice calculations.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks for the link. So, the theoretical radius is 0.566 +/- 0.272 fm? This seems smaller than the ranges of any of the experimental measurements.

Comment: Read the Conclusion section. It sounds like there are better lattice methods. You should try to find the other references. I provided a link to this paper because it wasn’t behind a paywall. I am no expert in lattice calculations so I can’t speak to the issue myself.